# Django ForeignKey null=True IntegrityError

Tags: python, django

I am making a comment and reply system, where the comments should have parent as null in the database and the replies have the id of the parent comment. Below is my comment model, for your reference. When I am trying to post the comment via my form, I get `IntegrityError`. I tried putting both `blank=True` and `null=True`, but the error is still there. Also, I have figured out from the documentation and other articles that `null=True` should work, not `blank=True`. I cannot understand why I am getting the error and how to fix it. Thank you in advance.

```
class BlogComment(models.Model):
    sno= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    comment=models.TextField()
    user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post=models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent=models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    timestamp= models.DateTimeField(default=now)
```

Comment: Can you share the `IntegrityError` error message ? It could be related to the other `ForeignKey`s in your model. Also, did you use a migration to modify the `null=True` value in the database ? It could be that you haven't applied the change and are still seeing the effect of the previous version.

Comment: @JoseKilo It is working now. There was a typo in the name attribute of one of my input fields. Thank you for your help though :)

Answer (score 0):

This was not working because of typo in the name attribute of my form input. I fixed that and now it is working.